# Iterating efficiently in NumPy where next iteration depends on previous

Tags: python, numpy, endianness

I am trying to simulate arbitrary-precision binary arithmetic using NumPy. As a simple case, I have code (in basic, non-NumPy Python) that adds one to a binary number where binary numbers are represented as lists of 0s and 1s from least-to-most significant bits (so they read as binary numbers from right to left):

```
def increment_bits(bits):
    """
    Returns binary representation corresponding to bits + 1
    where bits is a list of 0s and 1s.
    
    >>> increment_bits([1, 1, 1, 0, 1])   # 23 + 1 == 24
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
    >>> increment_bits([1, 1, 1])         #  7 + 1 ==  8   <- an extra bit now needed
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
    """
    new_bits = bits[:]
    for i, v in enumerate(new_bits):
        if v:
            new_bits[i] = 0
        else:
            new_bits[i] = 1
            return new_bits
    # if we have made it here, then there is a final "carry"
    new_bits.append(1)
    return new_bits
```

My goal is to achieve the same effect, but faster, using NumPy, but I am new to NumPy and am not sure the fastest (or most NumPy-onic) way to iterate over a NumPy array to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I apologize if I did not explain myself clearly; I think the examples are correct - the idea is to read the binary numbers from right to left, so I think they are 24 and 8 , respectively.

Comment: "from right to left" - that should be in your description

Comment: `numpy` is NOT designed to iterate efficiently.  Stick with lists. `numpy` is a 'parallel' operation tool - acting on all elements of the array at once (or virtually so as seen by the python level programmer).

Comment: Ah, I see. I will look into alternatives. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the commenters that Numpy array is not the way to go, but I wanted to give it a try nevertheless. The main idea was to cleverly create a mask for where to add a one by using the cumulative product. This would create an array of 1's until the first 0. We then need to shift by 1 and then set the 0th index to 1 so we add one to every index until after the first 0.

The hope was that maybe numpy had a faster than O(n) implementation of cumulative product, but the result was still slower than just iterating through the list. Also, there's always the overhead of converting to numpy array.

```
def numpy_bit(bits):
    mask = np.cumprod(bits)
    mask = np.roll(mask, 1)
    mask[0] = 1

    res = (bits + np.ones(len(bits)) * mask) % 2
    if np.all(res == 0):
        return np.append(res, 1)
    else:
        return res
```

Comment: But there can't be a faster than O(n) algorithm of a cumulative product.